# Change style (only) in element where <script> is located

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to change the font color of "a" and "h2" to "red", but only in the "div" where < script> is located (so only the second one). How can I do this **with Javascript**? (div, a, h2 shouldn't get an ID or class)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<div>
<a href="#">Link 1</a>
<h2>Hey</h2>
</div>

<div>
<a href="#">Link 2</a>
<h2>Hey</h2>
<script>
...
</script>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: this is not really any criteria to do that. `<script>` can be anywhere in your code

Answer (score -1):

So you cant give the parent div, the anchor tag, or the h2 identifiable properties. What if you give your script tag an ID? That way you could select the parent div and all it's children.